# Relative horizontal positioning of a line

Tags: horizontal-alignment

How can I set the second line so that the colons have the same horizontal position?

```
    \documentclass{article}

    \begin{document}

    \hfill foo : bar baz barabbas\\
    x : y

    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the help of a `tabular`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\hfill
\begin{tabular}{@{}r@{~:~}l@{}}
foo &  bar baz barabbas\\
x & y
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A solution with `eqparbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eqparbox}

\begin{document}

Some text. Some more text. Still some more text. 

\hfill \eqmakebox[L]{foo :} \eqmakebox[R]{bar baz barabbas}\\
\null \hfill\eqmakebox[L][r]{x :} \eqmakebox[R][l]{y}

\end{document}
```

[image]